# Есть ли формат файла + плагин для хранения команд, которые выполняются в консоли? (VS code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Например, у меня есть проект на JS , в котором я часто запускаю "npm run lint"  и еще кучу команд.

Вопрос: есть ли формат файла и плагин к нему, который бы мне запускал эти компанды по нажатию на кнопку в файле.  В общем мне нужно, чтобы я не держал все эти команды в голове, и не писал их в консоли каждый раз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файл называется `package.json` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts